# How can I make a for loop that creates a circle with a number inside?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can I make a for loop that creates a circle with a number inside.

For example 1 2 3 4, it always shows me 1.

Below my code

```
numberVariable: Array<any> = [0];

    @ViewChild('numberVariables', {static: false}) numberVariables: ElementRef;

    drawCircle(num) {
        let count = "1";
        let variables = this.numberVariables;
        if (this.numberVariable.length === 0) {
            this.numberVariable.push(1);
        }
        const span: any = this.renderer.createElement('span');
        /*span.classList.add("lineCircle");*/
        this.renderer.addClass(span, "lineCircle");
        span.style.borderColor = "#2A86CA";
        span.style.color = "#2A86CA";
        let line = this.renderer.createText("__");
        this.renderer.appendChild(variables.nativeElement, line);
        this.renderer.appendChild(variables.nativeElement, span);
        const spantwo: any = this.renderer.createElement('span');
        spantwo.classList.add("numberCircle");
        spantwo.style.borderColor = "#2A86CA";
        spantwo.style.color = "#2A86CA";
        let number = this.renderer.createText(count);
        let linetwo = this.renderer.createText("__");
        this.renderer.appendChild(variables.nativeElement, linetwo);
        this.renderer.appendChild(variables.nativeElement, spantwo);
        this.renderer.appendChild(spantwo, number);
    }
```

Here is the output of this code
[image: Here is the output of this code]

```
numberVariable: Array<any> = [0];
```

I start it at 0 because for that I do push 1, so I want it to go through and it shows every time I click on the sequence 1 2 3 4

my html file :

```
 <div id="numberVariables" #numberVariables class="card p-3" (click)="drawCircle($event)">
    <span class="numberCircle">
```

my css file:

```
#numberVariables {
  display: inherit;
}

.numberCircle {
  font: 20px Arial, sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  box-sizing: initial;
  background: #fff;
  border: 0.1em solid #666;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 2em;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 11px 16px;
}

.lineCircle {
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 2em;
  color: #666;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}
```

the result i want is this:

[image]

Comment: You can use unicode glyphs. `&#9312;` for enclosed 1  up to `&#9331;` for enclosed 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit hard to say without the rest of your code, but looks like you need to change:

```
let number = this.renderer.createText(count);
```

to:

```
let number = this.renderer.createText(num);
```

It's also worth mentioning that this is not the typical way of writing Angular components, ie heavy use of Renderer rather than template HTML and child components.

Comment: the num is a mouse event I am going to show what I imagine is to make it a for with a variable that I declare outside the class, I will add rest of code